# Twilio bitrate Android

Tags: android, twilio, bitrate

I'm using new twilio library and it works great.

Want to know what bitrate is during calls and how to set it.

Can't find it at server-side, seems it sets at client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the SDK engineering team:

Right now, it's not possible to set the bitrate manually for the audio portion of your Video Call. From the audio perspective, [the SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/sdks#android-sdk) will be using the Opus codec, and the settings will be essentially the libwebrtc defaults.

Ultimately WebRTC is going to optimize the VBR bitrate in realtime during the call depending on the changing network conditions. This should result in the optimal bandwidth utilization on a per-device basis.